# How this trade-off has been calculated for Regularized least-squares in convex-optimization boyd book

Tags: least-squares

I am reading this topic of boyd book from convex optimization, but the following division i-e trade-off least square and l2 norm are difficult to understand for me. If kindly someone can explain equation, that how it has been calculated. Your guidance will be appreciated. Regards,

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Solution for the least square regularization]

My apologies, please ignore my question. I have solved my problem. I am just posting the answer in case someone needed. In case the question is too irrelevant here, it can be deleted. Regards

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/73604)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this "multi-objective" task is known to be $A^\dagger \,b$ with the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) $A^\dagger$. If $A$ is injective, we have 
$$A^\dagger b = (A^* A)^{-1} A^* b.$$

In case $A$ is surjective, we have 
$$A^\dagger b = A^* (A\, A^*)^{-1} b$$

In the general case, one may apply [Tikhonov regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization):

$$A^\dagger \,b = \lim_{\lambda \searrow 0} (A^*A + \lambda)^{-1} A^\intercal  b = \lim_{\lambda \searrow 0} A^* (A\, A^* + \lambda)^{-1} b.$$

See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Limit_relations).